# Injecting functions in a (custom) enum container

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to transform the following code for an "Enum" object container:

```
/* enum.js */
let Enum = {};

Enum.Color = {
  check: (value) => {
    [
      'red',
      'green',
      'blue',
    ].indexOf(value) !== -1;
  },
};

Enum.Size = {
  check: (value) => {
    [
      'big',
      'medium',
      'small',
    ].indexOf(value) !== -1;
  },
};

export default Enum;
```

in such a way that is minimalistic and inject the functions?

```
let Enum = {};

Enum.Color = { values: [
      'red',
      'green',
      'blue',
    ],
  },
};

Enum.Size = { values: [
      'big',
      'medium',
      'small',
    ],
  },
};

// here some code that inject the check function and 
// other fcts to follows in every Enum property (lets say, with a values property inside) 

export default Enum;
```

This model is very flexible, because I could add other meta data to the different enums.

The use of enum is now and then as follows

```
import Enum from 'enum';
Enum.Size.check('medium');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (I don't know if it's minimalistic enough, but certainly *repetitionless*) is to create an interface/class which represents *checkable* entity, like this:

```js
class Checkable {
  constructor (values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

  check (value) {
    return this.values.indexOf(value) !== -1;
  }
}
const Enum = {
  Color: new Checkable(['red', 'green', 'blue']),
  Size: new Checkable(['small', 'medium', 'big'])
}

console.log(Enum.Color.check('green'))
console.log(Enum.Size.check('xxl'))
```

This way, adding other common methods is very easy. The most important advantage here is that this solution does not introduce any repetitions in your code which I see as an absolute win

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the following format:

```
Enum.Color = {
  red: "#F00",
  green: "#0F0",
  blue: "#00F"
};

Enum.Size = {
  big: "200px",
  medium: "400px",
  small: "600px"
};
```

This way you can also add more info to each enum (such as order, importance, classes or css values), will also being able to check if an enum exists using the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

```js
var Enum = {};

Enum.Color = {
  red: "#F00",
  green: "#0F0",
  blue: "#00F"
};

console.log("red" in Enum.Color);
console.log("black" in Enum.Color);
console.log(Enum.Color.red);
```

If you are adamant on having it look like you described then:

```js
let Enum = {};

Enum.Color = {
  check: [
    'red',
    'green',
    'blue',
  ]
};

Enum.Size = {
  check: [
    'big',
    'medium',
    'small',
  ]
};

Object.keys(Enum).forEach(function(key) {
  var list = Enum[key].check;
  Enum[key].check = value => list.indexOf(value) !== -1;
});

console.log(Enum.Color.check("red"));
console.log(Enum.Color.check("black"));
console.log(Enum.Size.check("tiny"));
console.log(Enum.Size.check("medium"));
```